# The foreign key component '.' is not a declared property on type '.'

Tags: entity-framework, ef-fluent-api

I have the following model :

```
            Public MustInherit Class Epreuve

            Public Enum EpreuveType
                CourseStade = 1
                ConcoursSansBarre = 2
                ConcoursAvecBarre = 3
                EpreuveMultiple = 4
                EpreuveCombinee = 5
            End Enum

            Public Property EpGuid As Guid

            Public Property FormatPerf As String

            Public Property CodeAppel As String

            Public Property Nom As String

            Public Property NomReduit As String

            Public Property Chrono As String

            Public Property Vent As Boolean

            Public Property Ajustement As Double

            Public MustOverride ReadOnly Property TypeEpreuve As EpreuveType

        End Class

    Public MustInherit Class EpreuveStade
        Inherits Epreuve
    End Class

Public MustInherit Class EpreuveComposee
    Inherits EpreuveStade
    Implements ISousEpreuve

    Public Property EpParentGuid As Guid Implements ISousEpreuve.EpParentGuid

    Public Property SousEpreuves As ObservableCollection(Of EpreuveStade) Implements ISousEpreuve.SousEpreuves

End Class

Public Class EpreuveCombinee
    Inherits EpreuveComposee

    Public Property EpreuveParent As EpreuveComposee

    Public Overrides ReadOnly Property TypeEpreuve As EpreuveType
        Get
            Return EpreuveType.EpreuveCombinee
        End Get
    End Property
End Class
```

EpreuveComposee and EpreuveStade has a many to may relationship.
Here is the fluent API i've done :

```
With modelBuilder.Entity(Of Epreuve)
    .HasKey(Function(ep) ep.EpGuid)
    .Property(Function(ep) ep.EpGuid).HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema.DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)
    .Map(Of EpreuveCombinee)(Function(f) f.Requires("TypeEpreuve").HasValue(DirectCast(Epreuve.EpreuveType.EpreuveCombinee, Integer)))
End With

With modelBuilder.Entity(Of EpreuveCombinee)
    .HasRequired(Function(f) f.EpreuveParent).WithMany.HasForeignKey(Function(f) f.EpParentGuid)
End With
```

When I try to add-migration, I get the following error :

> The foreign key component 'EpParentGuid' is not a declared property on
>   type 'EpreuveCombinee'. Verify that it has not been explicitly
>   excluded from the model and that it is a valid primitive property.

Comment: why is the navigation property read only?

Comment: TypeEpreuve is not a navigation property. On second thought, this property is useless. It is only the Type of epreuve (wich is the class type).

Answer (score 0):

I've found it.

```
Public MustInherit Class EpreuveComposee
    Inherits EpreuveStade
    Implements ISousEpreuve

    Public Property EpParentGuid As Guid Implements ISousEpreuve.EpParentGuid

    Public Property EpParent As Epreuve Implements ISousEpreuve.EpParent

    Public Property SousEpreuves As ObservableCollection(Of Epreuve) Implements ISousEpreuve.SousEpreuves

End Class

Public Class EpreuveCombinee
    Inherits EpreuveComposee
End Class
```

And the fluent API :

```
With modelBuilder.Entity(Of EpreuveComposee)
    .HasMany(Function(f) f.SousEpreuves).WithMany().Map(Sub(m)
                                                            m.ToTable("EpreuveSousEpreuves")
                                                            m.MapLeftKey("EpGuid")
                                                            m.MapRightKey("EpParentGuid")
                                                        End Sub)
End With
```